# Auto-execute command after going to a folder with the CD command

Tags: windows, command-line

Is it possible to auto-execute a command in a folder if you move to it via the cd command?

Of course I can define my own command (e.g. CHD.BAT) doing something like this:

```
@echo off
cd %1
if exist init.bat (
    init.bat
) else (
    color 0F
    title Command Prompt
)
```

But I wonder if something like this would be possible using the standard CD command.

Comment: Why do you need that anyway? Sounds fishy.

Comment: It was just an idea that I had to automatically set the window title of my command prompt depending on the current folder.  E.g. when in my development folder of release 1.0 of my application X, I want to set the command prompt title to "X 1.0".  This is useful if you are performing a big script in that command prompt window and you cannot scroll back to the prompt (which is indeed set to $p$g).

Comment: What do you mean "cannot scroll back to the prompt"? You can configure CMD.EXE's buffer (right-click the icon on the left top of the window, properties. Or something like that) to be able to scroll back a lot. If that's what you mean. Also, you could create a batch file to use instead of CD - something like `mycd.bat`.

Comment: When the script outputs lots of lines (e.g. one line for every file that is being compiled in a full compilation), 9999 lines are not enough.  But indeed something like mycd.bat would solve the problem.

Comment: I just wonder if it wouldn't be easier for you to compile from an IDE, or if you have a machine just for compiling, automate it. Also, why not edit the build script itself to change the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as this would be insanely dangerous. If it was, you could trick an administrator into executing random malicious code just by visiting one of your folders.

Comment: Good point.  This would indeed be very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating a doskey macro:

```
doskey cd=cd $*$Tif exist init.bat (init.bat) else (color 0f^&title Command Prompt)
```

However, it seems like output done in the `init.bat` file seems to get written after the usual prompt:

```
C:\Users\Me>doskey cd=cd $*$Tif exist init.bat (init.bat) else (color 0f^&title Command Prompt)

C:\Users\Me>cd stuff

C:\Users\Me\Stuff>Foo
```

(My `init.bat` in `Stuff` only contains `@echo Foo`.)

Comment: Even when `@ECHO OFF` is present?

Comment: It doesn't output the *command*, it outputs the *prompt* before the bat file's output is printed.